# What does "export RUBYLIB=<path>/gem/lib" do?

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, export

I've used `export RUBYLIB=<path>/gem/lib` in order to use the  adjustments I made to a Ruby gem on my local machine.  I don't understand what it actually changes. I have a script that opens up a few terminal tabs and if I want to use the adjusted gem I have to do this beforehand.

Can I just do `export RUBYLIB=<path>/gem/lib` once and not have to do it again? And what does it actually do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/rubyworld.html),

```
RUBYLIB - Additional search path for Ruby programs ($SAFE must be 0).
```

ie, `The list of paths mentioned here will be added to the list of paths Ruby uses to search for libraries included in the program with the require method. The paths in RUBYLIB will be searched before other directories`.

To make it as one time effort, append `export RUBYLIB=/gem/lib` to `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc`.